# How to Create Kapitza's Pendulum?

Tags: differential-equations, modeling, education

[image]
Hi, I have never worked on a project of this kind before. I am having difficulty using Kapitza's Pendulum (inverted pendulum with moving vertical base).

It is hard for me to make the model equations, and I am unsure how to plot the graph and display the pendulum animation.

```
eqns := {(-l1 θ''[t]) + g Sin[θ[t]] - c θ'[t] + Sin [θ[t]] y''[t] == 0};  (* motion equations *)
init = {θ'[0] == 0, θ[0] == π/4};

params = {c -> 0.69, g -> 9.81, m -> 1, l1  -> 1, ω -> π/2, A -> 1};  (* pendulum parameters *)
tmax = 10;

y0 = A Cos[ω [t]];
y0' = {l1  θ'[t] Sin[ θ[t]] - A Sin[ω [t]]};
x0' = l1  θ'[t] Cos[ θ [t]];
y[t_] := {l1  Cos[ θ [t]] - y0};
x[t_] = {l1 * Sin[ θ [t]]};
P[t_] := {x[t], y[t]}; 

psol = NDSolve[{eqns, init} /. params, {θ''[t], x''[t], y''[t]}, {t, 0, 15}];
Map[MatrixForm, eqns, 1] ;
Plot[Evaluate[{θ''[t], x''[t], y''[t]} /. psol[[1]] /. params],
   {t, 0, 15},
   PlotLegends -> {"θ", "X", "Y"},
   PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: my advice, do not use `Subscript` and do not use `l` as variable name. it looks like `1` on many screens depending on font. You can use `L` it is not used by Mathematica if you must.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. Could you please share some ideas for displaying Kapitza's Pendulum?

Comment: Your equation of motion for pendulum looks wrong. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum  why do you have $y''(t)$ in there? There should just be one equation of motion for angle of rotation. Is your pendulum not the same as the one in the linked wikipedia  page?

Comment: You can explore this [demo](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InvertedPendulumControls/) for pointers.

Comment: see also [KapitzasPendulum](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/KapitzasPendulum/) at Wolfram demo site

Comment: Thanks so much, am very grateful for your answers.

Comment: I remember reading last year Quanta M. article that was talking about analytical solutions. Maybe it was citing this one, but I am not sure.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363158309_Analytical_and_Numerical_Solutions_to_the_Kapitza_Pendulum_Equation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After small modification we have

```
eqns := {(l1 \[Theta]''[t]) + g Sin[\[Theta][t]] + c \[Theta]'[t] - 
     Sin[\[Theta][t]] y0''[t] == 
    0};                       (*motion equations*)
init = {\[Theta]'[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 3 \[Pi]/4};

params = {c -> 0.69, g -> 9.81, m -> 1, l1 -> 2, \[Omega] -> \[Pi]/2, 
   A -> 1};    (*pendulum parameters*)
tmax = 10;

y0[t_] := A Cos[\[Omega] t];
y[t_] := -l1 Cos[\[Theta][t]] - y0[t];
x[t_] = l1*Sin[\[Theta][t]];
P[t_] := {x[t], y[t]};

psol = NDSolve[{eqns, init} /. params, \[Theta], {t, 0, tmax}]


Plot[Evaluate[{\[Theta][t], x[t], y[t]} /. psol[[1]] /. params], {t, 
  0, tmax}, PlotLegends -> {"\[Theta]", "X", "Y"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Animation

```
points = 
 Table[P[t] /. psol[[1]] /. params, {t, 0, tmax, tmax/100}]; points0 =
  Table[{0, -y0[t]} /. params, {t, 0, tmax, tmax/100}];

frames = 
  Table[Graphics[{{LightBlue, 
      Rectangle[{-l1 , -(l1 + A)} 1.1, {l1, l1 + A} 1.1] /. 
       params}, {Blue, Line[{points0[[i]], points[[i]]}]}, {Red, 
      PointSize[.05], Point[points[[i]]]}}, Axes -> True], {i, 
    Length[points]}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 10):

Elaborating on Alex Trounev's solution. The trick with this inverted pendulum is, that for some frequencies it stays upright instead of falling down. Here is an example where I adjusted the frequency.

```
eqns := {(l1 θ''[t]) + g Sin[θ[t]] + c θ'[t] - 
     Sin[θ[t]] y0''[t] == 
    0};                       (*motion equations*)
init = {θ'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 3.9 π/4};

params = {c -> 0.69, g -> 9.81, m -> 1, l1 -> 2, ω -> π/2, 
   A -> 1};    (*pendulum parameters*)
tmax = 10;

y0[t_] := A Cos[5 ω t] /. params;
y[t_] := -l1 Cos[θ[t]] - y0[t];
x[t_] = l1*Sin[θ[t]];
P[t_] := {x[t], y[t]};

psol = NDSolve[{eqns, init} /. params, θ, {t, 0, tmax}]


p[t_] = P[t] /. psol[[1]] /. params;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.05], Red, Point[tmp = p[t]], Blue, 
   Line[{tmp, {0, -y0[t]}}]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-3, 3}}, 
  Axes -> True]
 , {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a very nice solution (+1).

Comment: In the animation the length of the line seems to grow and shrink, is that supposed to happen? (Wikipedia says it should be a rigid pendulum)

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing minus sign in the animation. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really do appreciate