# Mathematica model of the inverted pendulum with a moving vertically base

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having trouble deriving the equations of motion for an inverted pendulum with a moving vertically base in Mathematica. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out!

Comment: See this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278142/how-to-create-kaptizas-pendulum/278147#278147

Comment: Is the pendulum a rigid bar one, or a weightless rigid bar with a bob at the end? The dynamics are different in each case. You really need to give better specifications of the problem with diagram. Dynamics without diagrams is like reading in the dark.